# Tools for Hyperledger Fabric Development and deployment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hey could someone help me with this doubt?

I am a very beginner and not the typical profile of a developer. For a project I need to define the environment around blockchain. I need to define every tool you need  and everything to install to develop and deploy software using Hyperledger Fabric.

As far as I know I will need to install the prereqs:

- Docker Engine
- Docker Compose
- Node
- npm
- git
- Python
- VS Code
  All of them are considered developing tools, isn't it?

Other tools I need will be:

- Clients (CLI tools)
- Apache server?
- Playground. (What is that?)
- IDE
- Hyperledger Fabric (Is it similar to the EVM?)
- Loopback and Swagger??
- APIs

Anything else to add? Really thankful for helping me

Answer (score 0):

you wil not need a server initially during developement (can be done locally). An IDE (VSCode is one of them !) will not be needed if you are already getting VSCode. If youre a beginner - Hyperledger Composer (runs over a hyperledger fabric instance) would probably be better to start with. Playground as you mentioned is a user interface of sorts that helps in defining,deploying and testing blockchain networks (can be visited online at https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/). To develop networks locally you could download them and develop locally. There are many links available and if you need more I would be happy to link them ! (This series is also very helpful (IBMs ZeroToBlockchain playlist - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgGX-BTYOwA&list=PLnJzIOiv6cVTjaJRtJ2srarhs-m4V3zs3)

Answer (score 0):

[Hyperledger Explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) is also a very useful tool for viewing your network and the data stored in the ledger.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to check out **Chaincoder IDE.** It is a project I am working on. Helping people to get started with Hyperledger Fabric and uses almost standard CLI commands and configuration files of Fabric to get a blockchain system running either locally with docker or remote with different hosts. It is free and easy to use.

http://www.chaincoder.org/